# Can I create JavaScript objects inside ng-bind?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am quite new to AngularJS I was wondering if is it possible to create new objects inside the parameter ng-bind?

I need this as I do not want to edit my model in JavaScript after receiving from signalr(Loop over all the string dates everywhere in the model and parse them to dates) this is what I am currently doing...

I would rather use ng-bind to help create it in the view such as:

```
ng-bind="new Date(date).toDateString();"
```

I know you can access properties of a object in angular ng-bind as well as use other operations such as accumulative operations but is it possible to create an object like above.

Are there any disadvantages of this? as I understand the performance should be the same, the same amount of object initialization are occurring and "if" the date changes a new Date object with the new value will be created and the old one should be disposed.

Cheers.

Comment: You cant do that... expressions are evaluated against that respective scope. Angular parser does not evaluate js, it only evaluates a valid angular expression  And to me doing this way is a bad practice as well. These initializations are not meant to be on the view they should go to the controller. Also checkout datefilter, that may be of help

Comment: I would have thought it was bad practice to recreate a JSON model, that is standard in the company by transforming the standard model. By using a controller will it allow me to transform the string date to a date object usable by the view with out changing the model? If so then that is a solution...

Comment: Using the controller set up viewmodel to be bound to the view, if that means you want to convert string date to date object, i'd suggest to do so.. And format it either in the controller itself, or you could even use date filter on the view to format it.

Comment: Ill have a look at the filter you provided, It looks like it should be able to do what I want, I really want to do as least modifications to the model as possible and am trying to avoid a view model as all the data I need is already provided in the model just the date is a string not a date ;).

Comment: var workingModel = serverModel;  Then modify the workingModel.date property to look however you would like it to look. Then bind $scope.viewModel = workingModel. Or on the view: ng-bind=viewModel.date | date: 'shortDate'

Comment: Lol that's my current solution and I want it changed, PSL's suggestion on a filter might work for me so that's what I will try.

Comment: @PSL Cheers, the filter works, this has allowed me to bypass needing a view model. Do you think this is still bad practice even though the view model is redundant?

Comment: @Xela using filters in the view (for more or less static data) could add to additional processing each digest cycle. So generally while using a filter is fine but just that awareness could help. Also if your services are ui services and provide the actual model then they might as well provide formatted date to avoid any of these. But yes it is not that bad. Also worth looking at the built in [date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) if you have not done that already, works with standard date formats as well.

Answer (score 1):

As an answer to my question you can indeed create a object inside a ng-bind using a filter thanks to PSL for the idea.

Bind:

```
ng-bind="date | dateFilter;"
```

Code:

```
angular.module('app', []).filter('dateFilter', function ($filter) {
    return function (input) {
        if (input == null) {
            return "";
        }
        return new Date(input);
    };
```